# jsf popupwindow with a datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a form which one of it's fields is a code and description, also a button for opening a popup window that contains a list of all of the available codes. 
when the user double clickes a row from that table i want to set these values to the code and description. - how can this be done?

Another question, I want to create this popup and table to be initialized dynamically - by that i mean that if i have a few forms in my application, when ever i have a field which has a description i want to be able to open this popup and to see the available list for that field. (every field can be from a diffrent table). is it possible to create something like that? if so, how?

Any help will be appritiated,

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Even more, many component libraries have ready to use popup/dialog components, such as [RichFaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces) with [`<rich:popupPanel>`](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky) and [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) with [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf).

If you do not want to use a component library for some reason, you would need to create a custom component for this which generates basically an absolutely positioned HTML `<div>` element with a CSS overlay which get shown/hidden by JS on a particular click/action. The HTML/CSS/JS part should be relatively simple if you are familiar with those languages. The JSF part is somewhat hard if you have never created a custom component before, but it should be possible with a composite component as well, so you could also just create one with pure XHTML. The updating/refreshing can just take place by the usual `<f:ajax>` means.

Comment: I'm using `<rich:popupPanel>` and inside using `ExtendedDataTable`. I can't get the row values when im double clicking a row - i need to set the values inside the managed bean. do you know how this can be done? also regarding the dynamically initializing the table - can you refrence me to an example of that kind? thank's!

Comment: Just call the desired initialization action in the commandlink/button which should open this popup and if necessary, ajax-update the popup's content.

Comment: I think u didn't understand me.. after opening the popup, i have inside an ExtendedDataTable that contains all of the table record. when the user double clicks a row in that datatable , i want to close the popup and set the filed values in the form that opened the poup up. I can't find a way to use a double click event, that will call my managed bean..